# Generate automatically name of the sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to generate automatically the name of the sheet? For example I want to name the sheets in the following way:

"chart1", "chart2", "chart3"..

Thanks!

Comment: Do not edit old questions to ask an unrelated question. I have rolled back the changes. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; changes like that one are essentially vandalism, and will not be retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Worksheet.Name` property can be used to change the name of the worksheet in VBA.

This can be either done when creating new sheets, or set afterwards with the `Worksheets(x).Name`, where x is either the name of the worksheet you want to change, or an index.

For more information you can check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215978%28v=office.11%29.aspx) page about Worksheets.