# How to add worksheets in an automatic method and named them using a word/letter and a number?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question based on the following picture:

[image]

There are 7 groups with two columns each with a blank column between them.

I want to create a stacked line for every group and put the picture in another sheet. For example, I want to  create a stacked line from column A and B and put in sheet X1, then create a stacked line from column D and E and put in sheet X2, etc... Is there any posibility to name the sheet in that form such that to put letter "X" and numbers?

**The question is:** *How is possible to create sheets and named them with Xi(if I have 100 groups of 2 columns, I should have 100 new sheets named X1, X2, X3, ...X100)* and them put the stacked line from every group in the specific sheet?

Thanks!

Comment: `sheet.Name = "X" & counter`?  It's exactly the same as your question ["Generate automatically name of the sheets"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30710160/4088852) about charts.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code, so that we can help. You can't expect us to write a full macro for you.

Comment: @vacip I do not expect from you to write a full macro for me. This question arises from an older question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469241/vba-code-for-excel-how-to-create-graphs-in-separated-sheets. I thought that if I asked this question in a simple way I would receive an answer quickly. I will be happy to receive an answer. I really need this answer. Thanks

Comment: Well, you didn't show any of your code... right now your question is just a begging for free code with 0 effort on your part. Why _shouldn't_ you get a -1?

Comment: @takendarkk 0 effort? 0 effort from you to read all the comments. Please, try to be more careful before to speak about someone.

Comment: Just read all the comments - didn't find a single bit of effort from you.

Comment: @takendarkk read again and only then try to say something smart

Comment: Read again, still don't see it. Your code seems to be missing.

Comment: Please, don't follow this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided the steps  -

1) OPen a excel workbook 2) Press Alt + f11, go to insert module,  3)
   paste the code in the module 4) go the sheet1  5) Insert a shape for
   example rectangle  6) Right click the shape and you can find assign
   macro 7) Select macro, here Macro_Test 8) now you can run the macro
   by clicking the shape. Shape will act as button 9) After running, it
   will ask you to select a file .

Please look into the code. It will meet your requirement

```
    Sub Macro_Test()
        Dim LastCol As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim x As Long
        Dim wsx As Worksheet
        Dim col_num As Long

 MsgBox " Please Select the file"

    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)

        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        col_num = 1


        With ws
                LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With

        '~ for calculting no of sheet

                x = LastCol / 3


           For i = 1 To x
               wb.Worksheets.Add().Name = "X" & i
               Set wsx = wb.Worksheets("X" & i)

              wsx.Columns(1).Value = ws.Columns(col_num).Value

              ws.Application.CutCopyMode = False
              ws.Application.CutCopyMode = True
              wsx.Application.CutCopyMode = False
              wsx.Application.CutCopyMode = True


           wsx.Columns(2).Value = ws.Columns(col_num + 1).Value

            ws.Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ws.Application.CutCopyMode = True
            wsx.Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wsx.Application.CutCopyMode = True

           col_num = col_num + 3

           Next



        End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! A question please. This macro is running only if I put the information I need to be modified inside the file where the macro is? It is possible to have a macro saved with the name "Macro_test" and this macro to run with another workbooks?

Comment: @luli, I have added the code. You need to give input as file name

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Something is not very clear for me. Is there any method to make this  macro running for every excel file without giving the path and the file name of the files which I want to be modified? Thanks :)

Comment: You mean, you will give the path of the folder? , macro should automatically select the excel workbook and do this to each workbook?

Comment: No, I think no. I want to open the macro file and another excel file which has the structure from the picture and then press ALT+F8 and run the macro over that excel file. Then I want to run this macro over another excel file with different name and different  path. I think the right word is "Generally". I want to use this macro in  a generally way, without any dependence of name or path. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Now check the solution

Comment: It is going now. Today, I have learnt something new from you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99050/discussion-between-iuli-and-newjenn).